# SQL Management Studio Exporting Data

Tags: sql, export, mdf

I currently have a mdf database on management studio and I would like to export the data to a sql file. Exporting the data with the data-source: SQL Server Native Client works fine, but i have no idea where he saved the exported data. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go in Database->Tasks->Generate Scripts.

Select options there and you will able to generate complete db in SQL Script

Comment: Thanks, there was an advanced option where you could choose the version to what version you would like to export the data to. This worked for me.